# Apache rewrite to remove file extensions not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm attempting to use rewriting to add extensions so URLs don't have to have the extensions at the end, like .html. I've used the specific config for the rewriting before and I believe it worked so I was thinking it could be something else causing it not to work but I'm not that familiar with Apache. What's happening currently is simply getting a 404 when trying to access a page without the extension.

httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.d/*.conf

User ...
Group ...

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorDocument 401 /error/
ErrorDocument 403 /error/
ErrorDocument 404 /error/
ErrorDocument 408 /error/
ErrorDocument 500 /error/
ErrorDocument 502 /error/
ErrorDocument 503 /error/
ErrorDocument 504 /error/

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/plain .asc
    AddType text/plain .sha512

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on
```

The config for the specific host (Note that the proxy is for a different path, not paths I'm trying to rewrite for):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot ...
    ServerName ...
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
    SSLCertificateChainFile ...
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>

    #ProxyPass ...
    #ProxyPassReverse ...
    #ProxyPass ...
    #ProxyPassReverse ...

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

The modules config file also has this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the REQUEST_FILENAME wasn't giving the full system path. Two options to fix would be to place it inside a  or use "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"